# Facebook connect

Tags: facebook, ipad

Is there anyway of using facebook connect within an iPad or iPhone application.

The idea would be to sign into this App and then be able to see which of my facebook user's also use the app and its features.

Answer (score 2):

Yep.

The new version:

- Docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/
- Code: none, you write it yourself using the Graph API

The old version:

- Docs: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK
- Code: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the tutorial for Facebook SDK integration for you app from below link:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Then test the app. If you need to run the same code for iPad also, and if you want to resize Facebook controls for iPad, just follow instructions from:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=54307

But take care of few things:
In FBDialog.m
1) for 'postDismissCleanup' function don't comment the line,
[self removeObservers];
Otherwise your application will start crashing.

2) Replace both of these functions

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
  //UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
  /*if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    _webView.frame = CGRectInset(_webView.frame,
      kPadding + kBorderWidth,
      kPadding + kBorderWidth + _titleLabel.frame.size.height);
  }*/

  _showingKeyboard = NO;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
  //UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
  /*if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    _webView.frame = CGRectInset(_webView.frame,
      -(kPadding + kBorderWidth),
      -(kPadding + kBorderWidth) - _titleLabel.frame.size.height);
  }*/

  _showingKeyboard = YES;
}
```